# Can't get item_name from PayPal return data array

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, paypal

Good morning!
I have an issue with my PayPal payment.
There is my PayPal form:

```
<form id="upsell_form_paypal" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/it/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="admin@test.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://test.com/thank-you.php?type=upsell&payment=paypal">
<input type="hidden" id="upsell_notify_url" name="notify_url" value="https://test.com/payment.php?type=upsell">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="Upsell-1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="paypal_amount" value="0.01"><!-- PRICE -->
<input type="hidden" name="custom" id="paypal_custom" value="170907265"><!-- DEAL ID-->
<input type="hidden" name="payment_type" id="paypal_type_1234565" value="upsell"><!-- DEAL ID-->

<input type="image" class="image" style="margin-top:0" src="https://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/pagadesso.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Pay via PayPal">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

This array I get after payment. In my notify_url file, I can get all variable values except item_name. item_name is empty and I can't get it value.

[image]

What could it be? On Friday item_name working fine and I got its value, but from yesterday I can't get it anymore...

Comment: But I can see `item_name: Upsell-1` in your attached document.

Comment: @ankit yes, I have it in an array, but I can't get item_name value in the notify_url file payment.php, where I should add this value to my database. In this file $_POST['item_name'] is empty.